# How do I manage multilingual versions of my website with WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, duplicate-content, cms, international

We are currently publishing about 2 articles a week on English site which we would be translating in-house and publishing through Wordpress CMS to our new international sites in France and Brazil. We will be changing out photos and videos at times in addition to all the text/copy.

Should I use some sort of WP Plugin that will let me manage each of these through 1 WP install or is it better to run each separately through multiple WP installs?

I want to achieve this while...

- avoiding any duplicate content penalties.
- providing easy admin/editor management of publishing content.

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plugin WPML is great for this job and will solve all your problems.

You'll not have duplicate content because, in fact, the content will be the same but in other language. No problem with the photos here too.

WPML is possible to use "folders" like www.example.com/fr or subdomains like fr.example.com, so you'll have absolute control on your content.

I would run away from multiple installations has having everything together is better for managing and the available tools work very well.

http://wpml.org/ is the way to go.

Comment: I like WPML. Thank you for sharing! I totally agree about multiple installs. That just sounds like a nightmare long term. Especially if we keep adding new language support as we expand. I also discovered [https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press](https://wordpress.org/plugins/multilingual-press). Looks like it can provide ccTld and ability to manage all through a single WP Site with Pro version. Both of these plugin solutions would lose the potential SEO benefit from local hosting, but efficient management might beat that. Need to dig into this a bit more. Thanks again!

Comment: There is no real SEO benefit from local hosting, it doesn't matter where you host if you have localised your site other ways (in GWT, rel="alternate" hreflang="). It can however make a difference in site speed for your localised users.